# I cannot load WebGL examples in XAMPP webserver except WebGL-experimental

Tags: webgl, demo

I was using webgl-experimental code do display a webgl-demo on a custom webpage on an XAMPP webserver. After that I tried some non-experimental code:  https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/webgl-skybox.html
Changing the code to exactly the same like on the demo webpage (using CTRL-U to copy out the exact code) it didn't work.

Opening the demo in the same browser, it displays the running demo, but if I load it in my custom XAMPP webserver it won't load.

Why is it so? Is it also on the webserver dependent?
How to install a debug console, that can also print webgl errors?

https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/webgl-skybox.html

Comment: are there any error messages in your browser's [javascript console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/javascript)?

Comment: ReferenceError: Clazz is not defined m4.js:1:1
    <unknown> http://localhost/resources/m4.js:1
ReferenceError: webglUtils is not defined content_frame.html:60:17
    main http://localhost/content_frame.html:60
    <unknown> http://localhost/content_frame.html:243

Comment: Where can I get a proper m4.js?

Comment: https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-setup-and-installation.html